# How can I access a file in my home/folder-name on a Vultr VPS setup?

Tags: php, server, centos, vps, vultr

I have recently setup a [Vultr](https://my.vultr.com/) [VPS](https://www.ibm.com/cloud/learn/vps) and created a folder inside the `/home/` directory named `py-bridge`,
I then try to access a simple `.php` file with the path: `/home/py-bridge/index.php` via the Chrome browser.

But I get this returned back to my screen:

[image]

*The url I am using on browser is*: 
http://`my main-ip`/py-bridge/index.php

**VPS Information:**

**OS**: CentOS 9 Stream x64

*Thanks in advance for your time and effort!*

Comment: Have you tried Installing a Panel software? Vultr comes with a bunch of pre-set Cpanel, VestaPanel etc... Softwares that can help you create file paths easier to reach.

Comment: Hello @PeriklisKakarakidis, I used CPanel to create a directory and it worked thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course that won't work. That's now how web services work

You need a web server that can respond to http requests and sends back the file requested [py bridge in your case]

So either write a proper http server that does this

or front your php script with nginx and php-fpm and use that